# javascript adobe words not showing up in "this.getPageNthWord"

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I'm writing code to format PDF's which are automatically generated by proprietary program. I've developed the following code to accomplish the following objective:

1. Look through the first 10 words of every page. If the words "Evaluations" and "Summary" show up sequentially, delete every page between that page and the end of the document.

On some files it works perfectly, but on others the task doesn't delete the final pages. When I run this.getPageNthWord("index of page that has Evaluation Summary on it", "index of Evaluation") it skips right over the word.

My first thought was that the word I'm seeing on the screen was an image file, but when I go to edit the pdf or search using ctrl + f, it shows up as text. It seems the backend software is generating the data and placing it on a mostly blank template and the javascript this.getPageNthWord function is only counting are the ones generated by the backend software and not the template.

My question is how can words in a pdf document not show up in this.getPageNthWord? Is there some other attribute they could be found as?

```
for (var p=this.numPages-1; p>=0; p--) {
     for (var n=0; n<10; n++) {
        if (this.getPageNthWord(p, n) == "Evaluations") {
          if (this.getPageNthWord(p, n+1) == "Summary") {
              for (var d=p; d<this.numPages;d++){
                  this.deletePages(d)
                  }
           }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turns out that getPageNthWord defaults to stripping out punctuation and whitespace, which somehow completely removes whole words/phrases in certain PDFs (my problem PDFs were generated by Ghostscript 8.71). If that's the case, there's a good chance that if you set the bStrip parameter of getPageNthWord to false that it will work. And you'll also need to remove the remaining whitespace with trim().

```
for (var p=this.numPages-1; p>=0; p--) {
 for (var n=0; n<10; n++) {
    if (this.getPageNthWord(p, n, false).trim() == "Evaluations") {
      if (this.getPageNthWord(p, n+1, false).trim() == "Summary") {
          for (var d=p; d<this.numPages;d++){
              this.deletePages(d)
              }
       }
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little digging I figured out what the problem was! I stepped through each word on the page in question backwards and forwards and discovered that the words generated automatically showed up first in the index and the words I was looking for closer to the end. It seems that Javascript indexes for the words on the page refer to the order in which they were created, not in which they appear on the screen.

The pages I was trying to delete were on the bottom of the document. Having the script examine every word from the top down ate up too much processing power, but having it examine every word on every page from the bottom up sped up my processing time and deleted the pages I wanted gone.